# C# Find string in List<string> in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Have kind of a MongoDB issue here as Im trying to find a collection om matching IDs.
As Im building kind of a tree structure based on MongoDB. I have objects that contains multiple attributes like name, parents and children for them to know there relations.
Right now I can from and object go though its child ID and load each object one by one. I how ever noticed its much faster got get them as a collection.

So my question is now, how do I find ID of intrest in the collection on tree node objects represented in MongoDB.

example of how the mongoDB document can look

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("523de6c6d7b47f1f74c98ba2"),
  "IDType" : "root",
  "Name" : "test root",
  "Relations" : [{
      "Children" : {
        "ChildrenList" : ["523de725d7b47f1d0c8242f1", "523de746d7b47f1d0c8242f5"]
      },
      "Parents" : {
        "ParentList" : []
      }
    }]
}
```

So, how would I find one of the IDs by matching by a ID in the `ChildrenList`  ?
this as `Relations` is a array of `Children and Parents`. and these two contains array of IDs to be matched.

have tried this with out sucess.

```
IMongoQuery searchQuery = Query.ElemMatch("Children", Query.EQ("ChildrenList", "523de746d7b47f1d0c8242f5"));
```

Comment: The `"Children"` field is a descendant of `"Relations"` so minimally you'll need to include that in your query. `"Relations.Children"`

Comment: I also don't understand why the children and parents are stored in an array off of Relations, and then have an extra object level instead of being stored directly.

Comment: That's because there should be a possibility to have multiple parent-node-child relations for a single object. Not that I say that is usual, but as I have been in scenarios where this can be in use, I wanted to make this possible in the easiest way. Otherwise you have to fake it, and that can be quiet messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I found the solution thanks to WiredPrairie I thought I should post it.
The solution was apperantly not using ElemMatch for the parts but writing it like this.

```
IMongoQuery searchQuery = Query.EQ("Relations.Parents.ParentList", objectID);
```

Thanks anyways for the help to the right direction.